# Eloquent model binding not working when using Vendor package

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using the following package [Spatie Laravel Mail Templates](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-database-mail-templates).

I have created a resource controller to CRUD the templates and the following route declaration:

```
Route::resource('mailtemplates', 'MailTemplateController');
```

If I visit `/mailtemplate/1` it is not loading the model using the primaryKey, it only is just passing through `1` in the method. In my controller:

```
use Spatie\MailTemplates\Models\MailTemplate;

...

public function show(MailTemplate $mailTemplate)
```

Response from `dd($mailTemplate)`

```
MailTemplate {#592 ▼
#guarded: []
#connection: null
#table: null
#primaryKey: "id"
#keyType: "int"
+incrementing: true
#with: []
#withCount: []
#perPage: 15
+exists: false
+wasRecentlyCreated: false
#attributes: []
#original: []
#changes: []
#casts: []
#dates: []
#dateFormat: null
#appends: []
#dispatchesEvents: []
#observables: []
#relations: []
#touches: []
+timestamps: true
#hidden: []
#visible: []
#fillable: []
}
```

Strange that connection and table are both null?

I can see in the [MailTemplate class](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-database-mail-templates/blob/master/src/Models/MailTemplate.php) it is extending Eloquent Model.

Any suggestions why it's not loading?

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: It's not throwing an error, it's just not loading the eloquent model using the id value sent through.

Comment: If both connection and table are both null, wouldnt you need a template saved in the db?

Comment: @thisiskelvin sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Try changing `$mailTemplate` to `$mailtemplate` in the controller arguments (lowercase t)

Comment: @Bryan same result

Comment: Can you do `php artisan route:list` and post what the show method looks like there? I think you just have the wrong variable name here.

Comment: Thanks that helped to resolve the issue. I'd changed the route to `Route::get('mailtemplates/{mailTemplate}', 'MailTemplateController@show');`. Fix was using lowercase in controller and route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `$mailTemplate` to `$mailtemplate` in the controller parameters (lowercase t)

In the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers) you can see by default the parameter name is the singular version of the resource. Given your resource name `mailtemplates` I would expect the correct parameter name to be `mailtemplate`

Variables in php are case sensitive, so .`$mailTemplate` is not matching.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the mismatch of route parameter and `show()` functions parameter name.

So either change your route or change your show function.

**Solution one: Create custom route**

```php
// in this case you cant stick with resource route
Route::get('mailtemplates/{mailTemplate}', 'MailTemplateController@show');
```

**Solution two: change show function**

```php
public function show(MailTemplate $id)
```

Comment: That is just returing the primaryKey/ID in the controller as well? What I would like is to use the primaryKey in the route and for Laravel to perform it's magic and bind it to the associated Eloquent model.

Comment: This is not correct. In the docs you can see by default the parameter name is the singular version of the resource: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers . The way he had it before looks like it is correct except for the casing.

Comment: I think then it should be 'mail-templates' in the route. right?